# Can gatling load test SQL database or MongoDB?

Tags: scala, load-testing, gatling

I need to make load testing on my persistent storages Postgres and MongoDB.

I'm wondering if it is possible to do with gatling? Because as I see gating supports only http and jms out of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, it was under discussion some time ago, however the functionality didn't appear to have high enough demand from the community hence it was discarded.

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) for database testing, it comes with [MongoDB Script](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#MongoDB_Script_(DEPRECATED)) sampler for Mongo and [JDBC Request sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) for any other databases which support [JDBC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Database_Connectivity) protocol.

New JMeter tests and existing Gatling tests can be combined into a single test harness via i.e. [Taurus](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Index/) tool which supports [JMeter](http://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/), [Gatling](http://gettaurus.org/docs/Gatling/) and few more underlying load testing tools.

Comment: This is very sad... I like gatling, but this feature is critical for me, so I have to chose JMeter instead.